# How to get Redis key values on Server side Dart with Angel

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, redis, nginx-reverse-proxy, angel-framework

Having moved my mobile app development to Flutter I am now in the process of experimenting with using Dart as my main server side language. The productivity benefits in using a single coding language in both the app and on the server are considerable.  To that end I have set up a server with an Nginx front end which proxies all dynamic web requests to an [Angel/Dart](https://pub.dev/packages/angel_framework) server.

Angel is a remarkably well written package and I had a working server written up in no time at all.  However, in order to have a fully functional backend I need to be able to use both Redis and PostgreSQL from within my server side Dart code.  I am using the [resp_client](https://github.com/blimster/resp_client) package to access Redis.  The issue I have run into is with the fact that [RespCommand.get](https://pub.dev/documentation/resp_client/latest/resp_commands/RespCommands/get.html) is asynchronous.  With my newbie knowledge of both Dart and Angel I am unable to find a way to acquire a Redis key value via `RespCommand.get` in an Angel route handler and then somehow use that value in the response it returns.

My entire Dart backend server code is shown below

```
import 'package:angel_framework/angel_framework.dart';
import 'package:angel_framework/http.dart';
import 'package:postgres/postgres.dart';
import 'package:resp_client/resp_client.dart';
import 'package:resp_client/resp_commands.dart';


class DartWeb
{
 static Angel angel;
 static AngelHttp http;
 static RespCommands redis;
 static PostgreSQLConnection db;

 static init() async
 {
  angel = Angel();
  http = AngelHttp(angel);
  angel.get('/',rootRoute);
  await prepareRedis();
  await http.startServer('localhost',3000); 
 }

 static prepareRedis() async
 {
  RespServerConnection rsc =  await connectSocket('localhost');
  RespClient client =  RespClient(rsc);
  redis = RespCommands(client); 
 } 

 static preparePostgres() async
 {
  db = new PostgreSQLConnection('serverurl',portNo,'database',username:'user',password:'password');
  await db.open(); 
 }

 static void rootRoute(RequestContext req,ResponseContext res)
 {
  try
  { 
   await redis.set('test','foobar',expire:Duration(seconds:10));
   String testVal = await redis.get('test');
   res.write('Done $testVal'); 
  } catch(e) {res.write('++ $e ++');}
 }
} 

main() async {await DartWeb.init();}
```

If I start up this server and then access it through my web browser I end up with a 502 Bad Gateway message.  Not surprising.  `dart2native main.dart -o mainCompiled` returns the error `await can only be used in async...` message.

So I tried instead

```
try
{ 
 res.write('Before');
 redis.set('test','foobar',expire:Duration(seconds:10)).then((bool done)
 {
  res.write('DONE $done'); 
 });
 res.write('After');
} catch(e) {res.write('++ $e ++');}
```

which simply printed out `BeforeAfter` in my browser with the **DONE** bit never showing up although a quick test via `redis-cli` shows that the key `test` had in fact been created.

My knowledge of both Dart and Angel is still in its infancy so I guess I am doing something incorrectly here.  Shorn of all the detail my questions are essentially these -

- how do I call and get the result from `async` methods in an Angel route dispatcher?
- given that I am editing my Dart code in VSCode on my local Windows machine which accesses the relevant dart files on my Ubuntu server I loose the benefits of error reporting provided by the VSCode Dart plugin.  `dart2native`, as I have used here, helps out but it would be nicer if I could somehow get a running error report within VSCode as I do when building Flutter apps locally.  How can I accomplish this - if at all possible?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that Dart/Angel does not impose excessively strict constraints on the signature of a route handler.  So you can quite safely declare a route handler like this one

```
 static Future<void> rootRoute(RequestContext req,ResponseContext res) async
 {
  try
  { 
   res.write('!! Before '); 
   await redis.set('test','foobar',expire:Duration(seconds:10));
   String test = await redis.get('test');
   res.write('After $test !!');
  } catch(e) {res.write('++ $e ++');} 
 }
```

With the route simply returning a Future we can now safely do anything we like there - including calling other asynchronous methods: in this instance to fetch a Redis key value.